# Assign column value based on corresponding column - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like the NA values in column b to be filled based on how the other values in column b correspond with the values in column a. For example:

Dataset before:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  a = rep(1:5, each=5),
  b= c(NA,2,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,3,3,3,9,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,7,7,7,NA,NA)
)
```

Dataset after:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  a = rep(1:5, each=5),
  b= c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,9,9,9,9,9,2,2,2,2,2,7,7,7,7,7)
)
```

Note: My actual dataset has around 80,000 entries.

Comment: Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, `df1 %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  fill(b, .direction = 'updown')
`

Comment: @RonakShah it's not what OP intended. `join` should work here.

Comment: @Neel `identical(df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% fill(b, .direction = 'updown') %>% data.frame(), df2)` returns `#[1] TRUE`

Comment: @RonakShah, it's true. but objective is different. we have second `df` which is not output df.